# Linear regression returning bad fit with large x values

Tags: linear-regression

I'm looking to do a linear regression to determine the estimated date of depletion for a particular resource. I have a dataset containing a column of dates, and several columns of data, always decreasing. A linear regression using scikit learn's LinearRegression() function yields a bad fit.

I converted the date column to ordinal, which resulted in values ~700,000. Relative to the y axis of values between 0-200, this is rather large. I imagine that the regression function is starting at low values and working its way up, eventually giving up before it finds a good enough fit. If i could assign starting values to the parameters, large intercept and small slope, perhaps it would fix the problem. I don't know how to do this, and i am very curious as to other solutions.

Here is a link to some data-
https://pastebin.com/BKpeZGmN

And here is my current code

```
model=LinearRegression().fit(dates,y)
model.score(dates,y)

y_pred=model.predict(dates)

plt.scatter(dates,y)
plt.plot(dates,y_pred,color='red')
plt.show()

print(model.intercept_)
print(model.coef_)
```

This code plots the linear model over the data, yielding stunning inaccuracy. I would share in this post, but i am not sure how to post an image from my desktop.

My original data is dates, and i convert to ordinal in code i have not shared here. If there is an easier way to do this that would be more accurate, i would appreciate a suggestion.

Thanks,
Will

Comment: Out of curiosity, i divided the column containing ordinals (large numbers) by 1000, so my x and y axis were both in the hundreds. I am experiencing the same inaccuracy, however. Very interesting, yet frustrating.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IfIlYBt.png

Comment: Subtract the minimum date (X) value from all date values, so that the date values start at zero. There is no need to scale by 1000.